# How to add Email address in sales orders admin grid?

Tags: magento-1.9, email, sales-order, column

Trying to add email address into the grid in sales but once added can't search by  order number. Throwing error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'increment_id' in where clause is ambiguous, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`
>    INNER JOIN `customer_entity` ON main_table.customer_id = customer_entity.entity_id WHERE (`increment_id` LIKE '%0013%')

my code:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $customer_entity = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('customer_entity');
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());

    $collection->getSelect()
           ->join(
           $customer_entity,
           'main_table.customer_id = '.$customer_entity.'.entity_id', array('customer_email' => 'email'));
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

and field definition:

```
        $this->addColumn('customer_email', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('Sales')->__('Email'),
        'width'     => '100px',
        'index'     => 'customer_email',
        'type'        => 'text',

    ));
```

what to do to make it work ?
To display email I can just add a column but then while I'm trying to search by email magento throwing an error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'customer_email' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table` WHERE (`customer_email` LIKE '%custom%')

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, you need to get the customer email by performing a join with `sales_flat_order` table. Your `_prepareCollection()` function will be:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
           array('ordersTable'=>'sales_flat_order'),
           'ordersTable.entity_id = main_table.entity_id',
           array('ordersTable.customer_email')
         );
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

In `_prepareColumns()` you'll need to add:

```
$this->addColumn('customer_email', array(
            'header' => $this->helper('sales')->__('Email'),
            'index' => 'customer_email',
            'filter_index' => 'ordersTable.customer_email',
        ));
```

Now, to fix the search issue on order number, you'll need to add `'filter_index'` on 'order number' column. The issue is happening because there is duplicate increment_id column. Here is the code:

```
$this->addColumn('real_order_id', array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order #'),
            'width' => '80px',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'index' => 'increment_id',
            'filter_index'=>'main_table.increment_id'
        ));
```

Comment: Already sorted but thank you Alex ;)

Comment: The only problem I've had was  "ambiguous" but ... I found how to fix it ;) Also I found other solution, creating additional renderer but it was just overcomplicated :)

Comment: Glad to hear that, good luck !

Answer (score 2):

To avoid "ambiguous"

`filter_index' => 'main_table.grand_total`

is required.
Problem solved.